# PHP-How to make a beautiful calendar in php with css

Tags: php, html, css, calendar

I'm now developing an online software in php in which it uses a number of date pickers. I already tried the basic calendars and HTML5 calendar too. but HTML5 calendar not supported on Mozilla.

When I browsed on stylish calendars in php, I found a calendar ui, but I don't get the code of the calendar. Here is the snapshot of that calendar. I want to create a calendar like this.

[image: calendar]

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: i already tried it, but it not upto that.

Comment: I found my requirement. i found at this link http://metroui.org.ua/calendar.html . it may also help you in various css styles

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, here you can download the codes as well.

[link] http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-calendar-date-picker-scripts-for-web-developers/

Comment: nice collection of calenders.

Comment: @ShifanaMubi please click on the check mark, if you find it helpful so that others also find it useful. thank you.

Comment: yes it is helpful,but im waiting for more ans. if i didn't get ans anymore , then i accept ur ans.

Answer (score 0):

try Jquery date picker for that it may help you

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
      <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    href="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/css/datePicker.css" />
    <script src="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jscodes.com/codes/calendar_javascript/demo/js/jquery.datePicker-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Content Delv Logs</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function() {
            $('#date-pick').datePicker({clickInput: true});
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <input type="text" name="date" id="date-pick" value=""/>
</body>
```